# How to virtualize only the bottom of list items?

Tags: reactjs, list, react-virtualized

I can't delete components that I have already shown because of ads placed in items of the list.

(Here is [description](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en) why I can't delete ads)

So I want to virtualize only items below and when I'm scrolling down do not delete items that I have already shown already.

Current behavior:
[image: Current behavior]

Expected behavior:
Without logs from componentWillUnmount
(Bottom components still virtualized and won't mounting)

Here's [a CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactvirtualized-list-5bdl6)!

Or maybe somebody nows another tool that can help me?

Comment: You should show any attempts to solve your problem.

Comment: I read the documentation but didn't find what would solve this problem.

Comment: Documentation of what? Which components you using, how your react app looks like.

Comment: Documentation of react-virtualized. I've added sandbox link in main post.